# Compensa migrar do Swing para JavaFX?

Tags: java, java-ee, swing, javafx

Atualmente a maioria das minhas aplicações são feitas com Swing. Já fiz 2 projetos pequenos *web* com JSF+Primefaces+Hibernate. Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Compensa sair do Swing e estudar JavaFX, ou é melhor estudar mais a parte Web e continuar com Swing para aplicações desktop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JavaFX pareceu uma ideia boa a princípio, ela trouxe várias novidades como:

- GUI mais sofisticada;
- UI desenvolvida em FXML (que é baseado em XML);
- Maior facilidade para usar o MVC;
- Suporte a CSS, e etc.

Enquanto o Swing é mais antigo e robusto, e apesar de muitos acharem que o JavaFX veio para substituir o Swing a tendência mostra que os dois continuarão existindo em paralelo, pois apesar das novidades não costumo ver muita coisa sendo desenvolvida em JavaFX, e seu suporte continua bem menor do que o do Swing.

A curva de aprendizado de ambas as plataformas não são das mais simples, existem vários truques que você vai aprender enquanto desenvolve e isso pode resultar em um atraso significativo para seus projetos enquanto você não dominar as ferramentas.

Eu diria que você deve migrar de Swing para JavaFX apenas se realmente precisar de UI mais modernas, com animação e coisas do gênero, ou se você quiser se aventurar academicamente. Tome cuidado caso queira fazer projetos profissionais em uma plataforma desconhecida, você provavelmente esbarrará em dificuldades que não serão possíveis de prever antes de iniciar o projeto e poderá ter atrasos além do esperado.

Caso você não tenha intimidade com nenhuma das duas ferramentas eu diria para começar com o Swing, pois existe muito mais código em Swing em produção do que JavaFX, então as chances de um dia você esbarrar com um trabalho em andamento de alguém que foi feito com Swing é muito maior do que em JavaFX.

Na verdade Java para Desktop é algo que não deu muito certo, pouquíssimas empresas usam essa solução e consequentemente se você estiver investindo para entrar no mercado de trabalho não foque em nenhuma dessas tecnologias, se aprofunde na parte Web. A parte Web entretanto exige que você saiba bem mais do que simplesmente o Java, você constantemente terá contato com outras tecnologias e deverá dominar uma gama muito maior delas, você não precisa ser especialista (se for, melhor), mas terá de saber JavaScript, HTML e diversos frameworks Web baseados em Java. Mas acredite, você terá muito mais portas abertas do que se quiser insistir em Java Desktop.

## TL;DR

Opte por JavaFX apenas se você realmente tiver a necessidade de UI modernas para Desktop, ou se estiver dando uma de curioso em um projeto sem data para terminar. Se sua necessidade for desenvolver algo em Desktop com Java e que não precisa de UI mirabolantes, vá/continue de Swing.

Se você está querendo se aprofundar em Java buscando entrar no mercado de trabalho mas sem um alvo fixo, esqueça ambos e vá de Java EE.

Comment: Entendi, cheguei a conclusão que vou apenas estudar JavaFX e continuar usando Swing para aplicações, já que não faz diferença as UI's modernas. E vou me aprofundar em Java EE também. Obrigado

Comment: @DiegoAugusto incrementei um pouco a resposta e adicionei a parte que fala sobre Java EE. Tinha parado para almoçar, por isso levei um tempo :) Talvez eu ainda adicione algumas informações mais para a frente, mas daí eu te aviso.

Comment: Por que não estuda Java para android?

Comment: @user24857 ele não perguntou isso :) Além do mais eu diria que eu não domino bem o assunto para dar minha opinião, mas sei que hoje existem muitas opções cross-platform que podem se sair melhor do que Java. Sinceramente não consigo falar com segurança sobre esse assunto, senão até acrescentava na minha resposta sem problemas.

Comment: Sim, a Google pensa em usar o Dart para android.

Comment: Parece-me um pouco baseada em opinião estão não @Math?

Comment: @JorgeB. eu acho que é uma pergunta válida. Se preferir ouvir outras opiniões leva pro meta ou pro chat

Answer (score 0):

Olá, bem vamos ver como é o Swing e JavaFX tirando suas semelhanças e diferenças.

### Swing

O Swing foi um sucessor do SWT que deixou a GUI mais melhor e também foi criados novos `Componentes`, também foi desenvolvido o Look and Feel em que pode melhorar sua aparência para a GUI do windows por exemplo.
Também foi um lugar para outros componentes desenvolvidos, e seu modo de criar uma GUI fica mais fácil com os designers como o WindowBuilder do Eclipse em que podemos organizar o Form (JFrame) e o código e adicionar novos métodos.

### JavaFX

O JavaFX foi também uma grande mudança (como foi citado pela resposta acima)

> - GUI mais sofisticada;
> - UI desenvolvida em FXML (que é baseado em XML);
> - Maior facilidade para usar o MVC;
> - Suporte a CSS, e etc.

> Enquanto o Swing é mais antigo e robusto, e apesar de muitos acharem que o JavaFX veio para substituir o Swing a tendência mostra que os dois continuarão existindo em paralelo, pois apesar das novidades não costumo ver muita coisa sendo desenvolvida em JavaFX, e seu suporte continua bem menor do que o do Swing.

O JavaFX é baseado em código `java` e em `xml`, sendo que parte dos gráficos passa para o .fxml o java iria passar somente em carregar o fxml e executar as ações e eventos escritos no .fxml, os IDEs não tem um designer integrado para desenvolver o JavaFX mas tem o programa SceneBuilder da Gluon para editar e organizar um .fxml.

### Resultado

Seria melhor dar um aprendizado em Swing porque o Swing é uma espécie de tutorial de como desenvolver um Form e depois para o JavaFX